# Magento 1.9 Image Url without cache

Tags: php, image, magento, url

I am new with Magento and I couldn't find a clear answer about this. In the browser, my site images show like this:

www.example.com/shop/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/820x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/i/m/image-name.jpg

I would like my images to show like this:

www.example.com/shop/media/catalog/product/i/m/image-name.jpg

I don't resize my images or use watermarks.

On media.phtml (app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml), I have this code:

```
<div class="img-holder<?php if($labelsoptions['labelsorder'] == 'sale_new'):?> labels-sale-new<?php endif; ?>">
    <?php if(($fancy['fancybox_status']==1) and ($fancy['fancybox_product']==1)): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image'); ?>" class="fancybox"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <a id='zoom' class="cloud-zoom" data-zoom="showTitle: false, adjustX: -5, adjustY:-5, tint: '#fff', tintOpacity:0.6, position:'inside'" href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image'); ?>"><?php
        $_img = '<img id="image" src="' . $helpImg->getImg($_product, 'image', $imgSize, null) .'"" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
        echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
    ?></a>
    <?php echo MAGE::helper('MyThemeOptions')->getProductLabels($_product, 'new'); ?>
    <?php echo MAGE::helper('MyThemeOptions')->getProductLabels($_product, 'sale'); ?>
</div>
```

I replaced this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image'); ?>"
```

with this code I found in google, but nothing happens:

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getBaseMediaUrl().$this->getProduct()->getImage(); ?>"
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Disable Magento cache (Admin -> System -> Cache Management)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to get full size product image:

```
$fullImgUrl = Mage::getUrl('media') . 'catalog/product' . $_product->getImage();
```

btw, you can use browser inspect feature to know what is outputted